# PHP explode function into MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, explode

How do I get this to work?
Trying to use the explode function and insert into my DB table, but the values are not being sent to my DB table.

HTML:

```
<select id="customer_name" name="customer_name" required>
    <option value="">Select customer...</option>
    <?php
    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM customer order by customer_name";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['customer_name'].'|'.$row['customer_ID'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO persons(person_ID, customer_name, customer_ID) VALUES (?,?,?)");

$result = $_POST['customer_name'];
$result_explode = explode('|', $result);

$person_ID = $_REQUEST['person_ID'];
$customer_name= $_REQUEST['$result_explode[0]'];
$customer_ID= $_REQUEST['$result_explode[1]'];

$stmt1->bind_param("sss", $person_ID, $customer_name, $customer_ID);

$stmt1->execute();

echo "<strong>Record saved....</strong>"; echo 'returning to add another person. If no more persons to add please close this window.';

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The above returns the errors:
Undefined index: $result_explode[0]
Undefined index: $result_explode[1]
However I'm not sure how to define these (I'm self learning on a step curve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer here for solution: https://www.stechies.com/undefined-index-error-php/

> While working in PHP, you will come across two methods called **$_POST** and **$_GET**. These methods are used for obtaining values from the user through a form. When using them, you might encounter an error called **“Notice: Undefined Index”**.

> This error means that within your code, there is a variable or constant that has no value assigned to it. But you may be trying to use the values obtained through the user form in your PHP code.

> The error can be avoided by using the **isset()** function. This function will check whether the index variables are assigned a value or not, before using them.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too concerned about removing the notice, the issue is the fields are not going into my DB table.

Comment: @Ashman what? how can you not be concerned about the error notice? that's like level one READ what the error notice says, then you will understand what your issue is, this notice is not a warning its an error its telling you why it's not working and you should know that even before your started coding, this answer is correct as it solves your problem just read what the link says and correlate that with your error.

Comment: Did you even read to the bottom of the article? Removing the notice is only a small part of that article. Read to the bottom to fully understand what is going on, why you are getting the error, why it's not doing what it is supposed to do and how to fix it. $_POST['customer_name'] is not being set ergo no data, nothing to explode, nothing to insert to the DB.

Comment: Yes read it. I'll try again as I'm not understanding. Very new to this.

Comment: There's plenty of example here to thoroughly understand $_POST: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Another thing, when you are just starting var_dump is your bestfriend.

Comment: ok thanks... I've figured it out:     $result = $_POST['customer_name'];
$result_explode = explode('|', $result);

$person_ID = $_REQUEST['person_ID'];

$customer_name = isset($customer_name) ? $customer_name : "$result_explode[0]";
$customer_ID= isset($customer_ID) ? $customer_ID: "$result_explode[1]";

Comment: @Ashman thats good that you solved your issue and i understand your are new so please next time i recommend you look at the error notice copy it then paste it into google you will most probably find an answer to your error Number one rule is read your errors fully so that you can grasp the extent of the error ~ have a great day :D

Comment: @Ashman good for you. There are plenty of examples in the php manual, I also recommend you check it out. @ DB_cont I fully agree. Understanding the error could also lead  to a more thorough understanding of the logic behind a block of code.